# Unexpected right margin from paragraph in html

Tags: html, css, margin

I'm working on HTML.
I tried to center div in parent.
But there's always right margin extended out of the div.
So, now I changed to just a plain text, but it doesn't solve the problem.
[image: Right Margin shown in image]
How to fix this one?

Comment: How is this a duplicate? I don't even know what is block.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That margin is because `p` is a block element.

Add following CSS.

```
  p.myDiv {
    display: inline-block;
  }
```

Comment: It solved my problem. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of *margin: 0px;*
Try *margin:0 auto;*

Comment: It results in both left and right margin.

Answer (score 0):

Try this one for your code.

```
<body>
<p class="mydiv">ok</p>
</body>

.mydiv {
width: 20%;
margin: 0 auto;
}
```

Comment: Now there is both left and right margin.

Comment: margin: 0 auto gives you this result. adds equal margins on both side to make the element centered. this is what you wanted, isn't it?

Comment: I want no margin at all.

Comment: in that case you can do this
body {
text-align: center;
}
.mydiv {
display: inline-block;
width: 20%;
}

Answer (score 0):

Paragraph is a block level element which takes the entire width by default. If you give width 20% remaining space will be filled with margin. If you don't want the remaining margin use inline block element. Check out w3scholl website for block and inline block elements.

Answer (score 0):

[Centering in CSS: A Complete Guide](https://css-tricks.com/centering-in-the-unknown/) canu you read CSS TRICKS

Centering things in CSS is the poster child of CSS complaining. Why does it 
   have to be so hard? They jeer. I think the issue isn't that it's difficult to 
   do, but in that there so many different ways of doing it, depending on the 
  situation, it's hard to know which to reach for.